# Drupal 7: When I make changes to a block, previous edits are replaced with the new once instead of adding up to the previous edits

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I have a drupal site built by a freelancer, there are few things which were confusing.

1. When I click the edit button for a node, I see the CkEditor - I tried adding HTML tags and some css to tags. Then I saved it. I found few more changes have to be done, so I clicked the edit button on the respective node and I found the tags/css I added were missing.
2. Similarly I clicked the edit button for some other node and I did not do anything, I just clicked the save button. The output was completed distorted(because few css was missing and some tags were missing too).

P.S - Am very new to Drupal and this might be a basic question. Please bear with me.

Comment: Be careful with text formats you're using (drop down below the textarea) : Full HTML if you want to write HTML/CSS. You can manage text formats at /admin/config/content/formats, and manage wysiwyg profiles (and modify rich editor options by the way) here : /admin/config/content/wysiwyg. Be careful : just switching from a text format to another can modify the field content.

Comment: @Flo - When I choose Full HTML - add HTML/CSS - save it. If I try to edit node again(am not able to see the added HTML/CSS) and save it without making any change to the HTML/CSS. Will the previously added HTML/CSS still be there?

Comment: It depends on your editor configuration, some element are stripped from content. The source button mentionned by Inlanner can be handful. BUT... it's always tricky, dangerous and inefficient to handle full HTML blocks, so I generally try to avoid it. Stay away from CSS / PHP / JS in blocks or nodes or views field or anything you type in Drupal administration interface.

Answer (score 0):

Set the text filter to "Full html" then click on "source" to insert html tags and css. Otherwise (surely a better solution) install the [Ace editor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ace_editor), a very useful module with a syntax highlighter for html, php, and more.